# Do I need to launch my app on the Google Play Store in order to send app invites through Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to send my friends on Facebook an invitation to download my app using the code provided by Facebook developers.

```
    String appLinkUrl, previewImageUrl;

            appLinkUrl = "https://fb.me/****9163*****";
            previewImageUrl = "imageURL";

            if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
                AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                        .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                        .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                        .build();
                AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
```

The Facebook dialog successfully shows up and I'm able to send invitations. It even shows that it has successfully sent, however, when I contact the recipient, they don't receive the invitation.

I have already made my project public, enabled Single-Sign On and Deep Linking.

Thank you for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for push notifications, then it might be good to know that it is not guaranteed.

> Test App Invites by checking for Facebook notifications. Under certain
>   circumstances, App Invites also sends a push notification, but this is
>   never guaranteed.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios/#testing

Ask the user to check in the native Facebook app under Apps > App Invites. It should be under the last menu of the app.

Also, check your App Dashboard settings for what Platforms have you added there: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID_HERE/settings/

The notifications will only surface on the Platforms that you support there. e.g If you have added iOS as the platform, then the notifications will only surface in iOS and not Android or www.

Comment: Unfortunately, they reported that it's not under their App Invites. I supported Android and that user is using an Android phone.